# I have problem to convert timestamp to date and time in android?

Tags: java, android, date, date-formatting, epoch

Hi when i using this code for convert timestamp to date. but i do not know when i enter the date now year timestamp  for get time it print 1970 year.
can you help me?

this code i using :

```
Date a = new Date(1586822400);
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String d = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

But:
[image]

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Date date = new Date(1586822400L*1000L);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

you need to convert unix seconds to milliseconds seconds by multiply 1000L;

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you avoid using the outdated `java.util` date/time API and do it using the [modern date/time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html), `java.time` as shown below:

```
LocalDate date = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1586822400)
                        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                        .toLocalDate();
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd").format(date));
```

**Output:**

```
2020/04/14
```

Note that the value you have provided is epoch seconds, not epoch milliseconds.

[ONLINE DEMO](https://ideone.com/M3bK4r)

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**